# App Config in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am using Flask in my app in python. Now I am moving to Web2py.

I am confused where `app.config` for Flask was set in Web2py.

For example:

`app.config['FOLDER'] = 'new/'`

Other things I am having trouble is what is

`redirect(url_for('file', filename=filename))` of Flask in Web2py. In this I am redirecting to function `file` with `file_name` as parameter

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It may be worth looking at the docs http://www.web2py.com/init/default/documentation

Answer (score 2):

web2py does not work the same as Flask, so you're probably going to have to look through the web2py documentation to understand how to use it. web2py doesn't have an exact analog to Flask's `app.config`. As for the redirect function, note that routing works differently in web2py. In particular, controller actions do not take named arguments. Instead, segments of the URL after the function name are available in `request.args`, and query string parameters are available in `request.get_vars` (as well as `request.vars`, which also includes variables in `request.post_vars`). So, the analogous code in web2py would be:

```
redirect(URL('mycontroller', 'file', args=filename))
```

and in the controller:

```
def file():
    filename = request.args(0)
```

Alternatively, you could put `filename` in the query string:

```
redirect(URL('mycontroller', 'file', vars=dict(filename=filename)))
```

in which case, it would be available in `request.vars.filename` instead of `request.args(0)`.